# How to Sort a datatable without sorting a Specified column?

Tags: c#, sorting, datatable

I have table of data..

```
----------------------------------
Sl.No | Name
---------------------------------
1     | A
2     | C
3     | B
--------------------------------
```

I want to sort in this order not that Column Sl.No not be changed..

```
-----------------------------
Sl.No  | Name
-----------------------------
1      | A
2      | B
3      | C
----------------------------
```

How to do it in c#?

Comment: How to sort a datatable without sorting a column (Eg: Serial Number Column)?

Comment: So you want to move the names away from their SI number to give them new SI numbers and order?

Comment: This should be solvable in SQL. Is that an option or must that be done on the DataTable only?

Comment: Sl.No and Name are independent of each other if this is a requirement. Is this the case? If true, then they should not be put together as rows in a datatable. Why does it need to be in a DataTable? What is the end goal?

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't do this with a datatable. I would use two `List<string>`. Just create them, insert all your `Sl.No` in one List and the `Name`s in an other one.
Sort the Lists as you want and create a whole new datatable.

The problem here is, that datatable have [row](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.data.datatable.rows(v=vs.110).aspx) structure and use basically trying to break this structure.